# Python: Script for running Excel VBA script not running

Tags: python, excel, vba, windows, win32com

I am writing because after seemingly searching half the internet, I could not figure out why this simple piece of code is not working:

```
from win32com.client import Dispatch

def RunExcelMacro(name):
    myExcel = Dispatch('Excel.Application')
    myExcel.Visible = 0
    myExcel.Workbooks.Add('C:\AC_Software\TestDatei.xls')
    myExcel.Run(name)
    myExcel.DisplayAlerts = 0
    myExcel.Quit()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    RunExcelMacro('Makro_test')
```

It is supposed to run the vba script "Makro_test" contained in the Excel file "TestDatei.xls". I tried different combinations of Python and Java versions (32 and 64bit) on the 64bit Windows 7 desktop machine at my office. I also tried different slah and backslash combinations in the path (back- and forward slash, simple, double). Unfortunately, the error message is in German. But in case some of you can detect anything out of this, here it is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\alloun\workspace\MyTestProject\root\nested\example.py", line 22, in <module>
    RunExcelMacro('Makro_test')
  File "C:\Users\alloun\workspace\MyTestProject\root\nested\example.py", line 16, in RunExcelMacro
    myExcel.Workbooks.Add('C:\AC_Software\TestDatei.xls')
  File "<COMObject <unknown>>", line 2, in Add
pywintypes.com_error: (-2147352567, 'Ausnahmefehler aufgetreten.', (0, u'Microsoft Excel', u"'TestDatei.xls' wurde nicht gefunden. \xdcberpr\xfcfen Sie die Rechtschreibung des Dateinamens, und \xfcberpr\xfcfen Sie, ob der Speicherort der Datei korrekt ist.\n\nWenn Sie versuchen, die Datei \xfcber die Liste der zuletzt ge\xf6ffneten Dateien zu \xf6ffnen, stellen Sie sicher, dass die Datei nicht umbenannt, verschoben oder gel\xf6scht wurde.", u'xlmain11.chm', 0, -2146827284), None)
```

Comment: Have you tried escaping the backslashes?

Comment: I just wanted to suggest to replace `'C:\AC_Software\TestDatei.xls'` with either `r'C:\AC_Software\TestDatei.xls'` or `'C:\\AC_Software\\TestDatei.xls'`. But as both `A` and `T` are upper case, it must be something else...

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi Did you try that? Here, `'\a\A\t\T'` resolves to `'\x07\\A\t\\T'`, so `\A\T` resolves to `\\A\\T`.

Comment: @David Is the file you try to access really where you expect it to be?

Comment: @glglgl, you're right, I stand corrected. Python does indeed interpret backslashes literally when the next character is not a valid escape sequence.

Comment: @All: Thanks a lot for your comments. Unfortunately, neither r'C:\AC_Software\TestDatei.xls' nor 'C:\\AC_Software\\TestDatei.xls' worked. About the path being correct, I guess it should be since if I check the properties of 'TestDatei.xls', it shows 'C:\AC_Software'. I now use Python 2.7 and Spyder, included in Python(x,y). My Java JRE is a 32 bit version and my OS is Windows 7 in 64bit version. Any further clues ?

Comment: Ok, problem solved: Since I saved a macro in it, the Excel file is no longer an .xls but a an .xlsm file. So basically my path was correct, the code was correct, but the extension of the Excel file was wrong. That was pretty stupid, thank you guys for trying to help anyway :)

Answer (score 0):

Here's the English error message:

> pywintypes.com_error: (-2147352567, 'Exception occurred.', (0, u'Microsoft Excel', u"'TestDatei.xls' could not be found. Check the spelling of the file name, and verify that the file location is correct.\n\nIf you are trying to open the file from your list of most recently used files, make sure that the file has not been renamed, moved, or deleted.", 'xlmain11.chm', 0, -2146827284), None)

Make sure you the path is correct and try a raw string `r'C:\AC_Software\TestDatei.xls'` instead.  I tried the same code and it worked with a file I had.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer Mark Unfortunately it did not work for me :( Maybe you can read my last comment and see if something related on the Python, IDE, OS and JRE I use makes sense to you.

Answer (score 0):

Please see below the code for running an Excel macro using python. You can find the code in this Site - Link.

```
from __future__ import print_function
import unittest
import os.path
import win32com.client

class ExcelMacro(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_excel_macro(self):
        try:
            xlApp = win32com.client.DispatchEx('Excel.Application')
            xlsPath = os.path.expanduser('C:\test1\test2\test3\test4\MacroFile.xlsm')
            wb = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(Filename=xlsPath)
            xlApp.Run('macroName')
            wb.Save()
            xlApp.Quit()
            print("Macro ran successfully!")
        except:
            print("Error found while running the excel macro!")
            xlApp.Quit()
if __name__ == "__main__":
    unittest.main()
```